# Centering of numpy image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, svm

I want to make an artificial intelligence application that predicts a handwritten number drawn on a canvas based on the MNIST dataset and prints it on the screen. Almost everything is ready for this. My algorithm running successfully in these code but I have a problem. The figure I draw on the canvas is not centered for estimation. I mean, the system cannot detect and predict the number I drew on the corner of the canvas.
**These are my codes:**

**The code I loaded the model**

```
    self.loaded_model = pickle.load(open('svm_model.pkl','rb'))
```

**Used As Canvas Container**

```
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(300, 300)
    canvas.fill(QtGui.QColor("black"))
    self.label.setPixmap(canvas)
    self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
```

**Predict button's function**

```
def predict(self): 
    
    self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
    s = self.label.pixmap().toImage().bits().asarray(300 * 300 * 4) 
    arr = np.frombuffer(s, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((300, 300, 4))
    arr = np.array(ImageOps.grayscale(Image.fromarray(arr).resize((28,28), Image.ANTIALIAS)))
    arr = (arr/255.0).reshape(1, -1)
    self.prediction.setText('Prediction: '+str(self.loaded_model.predict(arr)))
```

These are visualizations of my problem:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I can append all of my codes if you want.
I think cause of this problem is not centering the image to be predicted. Because guesses correctly when I draw in the middle of the canvas. I can't find of header in the stackoverflow about my problem. There are similar ones but no matter how hard I tried I couldn't set them to my code.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by leveraging SciPy's ND-Image function for finding objects in a labelled array [`scipy.ndimage.find_objects()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.find_objects).

Essentially, you would:

- find the slicing containing the object (assuming the object is whenever the values are different from 0)
- copy the part of the array within that slicing in the middle of a new array

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage


def recenter(arr):
    slicing = sp.ndimage.find_objects(arr != 0, max_label=1)[0]
    center_slicing = tuple(
        slice((dim - sl.stop + sl.start) // 2, (dim + sl.stop - sl.start) // 2)
        for sl, dim in zip(slicing, arr.shape))
    result = np.zeros_like(arr)
    result[center_slicing] = arr[slicing]
    return result
```

To test it actually works:

```
arr = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])

tgt = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])

res = recenter(arr)
np.allclose(res, tgt)
# True
```

Note that in case of mixed parity of the original array shape and the object slicing, the object cannot be placed exactly in the middle and it will be closer to the lower edge along that dimension (when printing these are the top-left edges for 2D arrays).

Comment: It works! Thank you for help @norok2. I have problem one more. I want to print the accuracy score of the prediction in the GUI. I'm using SVM model and I can't find this ratio in array returned from code 
**predict = self.load_model.predict(arr)[0].**
Can you help me one more time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that if you have a different problem, you should write a different question. From the info you just provided, I am unable to help you with that.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I will write a question one more time.